# What is the best thing to use?

Tags: android

guys. I want to make a runnable function with Postdelay about 50ms that will be adding Decimal number each time and send a result to activity so I can update this number in the View.I also need it keep running while switching to another activity. As far as I understand the best way is to put it in Sevice in a different thread so it doesn`t slow the UI. I am a beginner so I would like to get some advices from you guys. How should I do this?

Comment: For example: http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/11/running-service-in-background-on.html 
you could find many many examples from Google

Comment: I am sure "What is the best thing to use?" is the result of careful thought on how to make the least useful title you can...

Comment: well, sorry about that Amadan. 
Mr Neo, I know I can find it. I was just wondering maybe there is a better way to do this

Comment: Yes, you should *not* run it in the UI thread. You can use a service (like you suggested) or an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `PostDelay` handler for the delay.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        //DO something
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `View` itself with `View.postDelayed(yourRunnable, 50)`.